# Modal View Controllers appear behind Action Sheet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uiactionsheet

My modal view controllers are being shown behind my UIActionSheet, and my UIActionSheet is not getting dismissed. I am using:

```
[self presentModalViewController:composeTweetView animated:YES];
```

To present my modal view controller.

My action sheet is being shown from the tabBar:

```
[actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.parentViewController.tabBarController.tabBar];
```

This code worked on iOS 4.0.

```
if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        if (self.isLoggedIn) {
            [FlurryAPI logEvent:@"ST_REPLY_CLICKED"];
            composeTweetView.isDirectMessage = FALSE;
            [self presentModalViewController:composeTweetView animated:YES];
            [composeTweetView release];
        }
        else {
            LoginViewController* loginView = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
            loginView.delegate = self;
            loginView.isPostingComment = TRUE;
            self.isReply = TRUE;
            [self presentModalViewController:loginView animated:YES];
            [loginView release];
            [composeTweetView release];
        }
    }
```

**Summary:**

I have a UIViewController that contains a UITabBar. I am presenting a UIActionSheet which has a few buttons that present a modal view controller. When the modal view controller is presented, the UIActionSheet should dismiss itself and the modal view should be on the top of the stack. The problem is, the UIActionSheet does not dismiss, and the modal view is loaded behind it. This problem did not occur up until iOS 4.2.1

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Create a TabBar project, setting
   your Base SDK to iOS 4.2.1
2. Create a button or trigger to show a UIActionSheet
3. Allow one of the buttons in the UIActionSheet to present a modal view controller using the syntax: `[actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.parentViewController.tabBarController.tabBar];`

**Expected Results:**

```
1. The UIActionSheet should dismiss itself, and the modal view should appear in front
```

**Actual Results:**

```
1. The UIActionSheet does not get dismissed and the modal view appears behind it.
```

**Regression:**

```
This problem was not apparent prior to iOS 4.2.1
```

**Notes:**
I have tried other ways of displaying the UIActionSheet all of which don't work as intended:

```
//[actionSheet showInView:self.parentViewController.tabBarController.tabBar];
//[actionSheet showInView:[self.view window]];
//[actionSheet showInView:self.parentViewController.tabBarController.view];
//[actionSheet showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
```

Comment: is it working in 4.2? Actually I tested the App in 4.2 it is working fine.

Comment: works in 4.2. Does not work in 4.2.1

Comment: where did you get 4.2.1 from? In my DevCenter the latest XCode is from Nov 22nd and contains 4.2 not 4.2.1

Comment: yet another thing, broken/flimsy with each increment of iOS SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved in iOS5.

Answer (score 2):

In putting together a sample in order to reproduce your problem I took a look at the UIActionSheet delegate methods. I believe you can use:

```
actionSheet:didDismissWithButtonIndex:
```

instead of

```
actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:
```

I haven't tested it, but I believe you still get the same button number and it doesn't fire until the actionsheet has disappeared from the view.

Comment: The only delegate methods I am using are: - `(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` do I need to manually dismiss the actionsheet?

Comment: Still no luck :( with the new delegate method

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your problem sorry but everything works great for me. I have tried the following code in Simulator and on 4.2.1 iPod Touch 4G (both worked)

```
- (IBAction)doit {
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"title" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"not OK" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Absolutely" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
    [actionSheet release];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        UIView *v = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
        v.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [self.view addSubview:v];
        [v release];
    }
}
```

1. created the TabBar sample project
2. added button to firstView-nib and connected with the appropriate `IBAction` (have to name the `FileOwner` to `FirstViewController`)
3. set the delegate method in `FirstViewController.h` (`<UIActionSheetDelegate>`)
4. added the code above

//EDIT: ok I saw that you want to present it modally but even this works for me on 4.2.1

```
TMPController *tmp = [[TMPController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TMP" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:tmp animated:YES];
[tmp release];
```

maybe it works because I use `self.tabBarController.tabBar`, try that

Comment: so try that self.tabBarController.tabBar thing ;)

Comment: [actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.parentViewController.tabBarController.tabBar]; //no luck

Comment: hmm really strange, what device are you using? 'cause on my iPod Touch 4G iOS 4.2.1 (8C148) it works as expected. Try using another device or another XCode environment

Comment: i am using an iPhone 4 to test

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have already resolved this.  But I didn't see a clear answer above.  I was having exactly the same problem as you.  So in the end, it was an issue on my side, but what help me debug this was to add the actual action code in the method

```
actionSheet:didDismissWithButtonIndex:
```

as suggested by Matthew.

This proved that the view was actually dismissed.  That's when I realized that I put the UIActionSheet alloc in my viewWillAppear method.  So each time the view appears it re-creates the action sheet.

Answer (score 0):

This seems weird as the SDK Documentation states:

> actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:
>   …
>   The receiver is automatically dismissed after this method is invoked.

I can think of 3 possibilities why it may not disappear:

1. The main runloop (main thread!) which handles the animations and display stuff is not called. Do you work something heavy in your main thread like synchronous networking calls? (note the word "after" in the SDK text)
2. Somehow you schedule to show the action sheet multiple times
3. You display the same view controller instance modally that is already somewhere below the current view on the view stack.

Comment: i am not blocking the runloop, everything is asynchronous and the actionsheet is only being called once, along with the modal view controller, there aren't multiple instances. the weird part is that this has worked since i've been building on iOS 3.0...

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a quick sample app to test this out and it worked just as I expected (i.e., I couldn't repro your issue). It *was* a little different in that I didn't do a TabBar application but I'm still hopeful this helps. What I did with the `UIActionSheet` was to show it like this: `[actionSheet showInView:self.view]`. Maybe that will work?

Sorry for the rushed answer, I was on my way out when this caught my eye. :)

Comment: `[actionSheet showInView:self.view]` did not work for me unfortunately. same results. weird how my code works on all versions except iOS 4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced problems like this with iOS 4.2.
I think you should try with the following steps:

1. Create a separate method for the code you want to be executed on clicking the actionsheet button. suppose the method is *-(void)presentModalView{}*

2.Now in the **- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet  clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex** method,Call the *presentModalView{}* method for the clicked button index like this:

```
if(buttonIndex==0)
{
[self performSelector:@selector(presentModalView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
}
```

3.You can also try by different delay time.

Hope it helps..

Comment: no luck. still shows up behind the actionsheet, which doesn't get dismissed.

Comment: so sorry..not able to help you..but I have still not updated my iOS 4.2 to 4.2.1. So, not able to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue calling MailComposeView from AlertBox/ActionSheet caused the MailCompseView to come behind invisible screen.

I solved it by calling dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated: in the actionSheet button handler.

Comment: I tried dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated: in the handler but no luck